# MVC Dropdown List

Tags: asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdownlist :

```
<%=Html.DropDownList("memberInvoiceStatus", ViewData["memberInvoiceStatus"] as SelectList)%>
```

Can I set the default value in the view?

I am binding like this...

```
IEnumerable<PayStatus> memberInvoiceStatus = new List<PayStatus>(dr.GetPayStatus());
ViewData["memberInvoiceStatus"] = new SelectList(memberInvoiceStatus, "payStatusId", "payStatusText");
```

So i have a collection of memberInvoiceStatus (4 total) but i need the selected value of each

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A way in which you could solve it is to create a List.

Say your Pay status is something like this:

```
public class PayStatus
{
   int id;
   string StatusName;
}
```

so you would do something like this:

```
IEnumerable<PayStatus> memberInvoiceStatus = new List<PayStatus>(dr.GetPayStatus());

 var statusList = new List<SelectListItem>();

foreach(var status in memberInvoiceStatus)
{
    statusList .Add( new SelectListItem()
    {
       Text = status.StatusName,
       Value = status.id
       Selected = status.StatusName == "MyDefaultStatus" // or some logic that will mark as True the item that you want to be the default selected one.   
    }
}
```

I guess you could still use it like you are using it, but instead of pasing this:

```
ViewData["memberInvoiceStatus"] = new SelectList(memberInvoiceStatus, "payStatusId", "payStatusText");
```

you would pass:

```
ViewData["memberInvoiceStatus"] = new SelectList(statusList , "payStatusId", "payStatusText");
```

although I think it is easier if you just added the list of `SelectListItem` to the viewdata

```
ViewData["ListOfStatus"] = statusList;
```

and in the view you do something like this:

```
<%= Html.DropDownList("Status",ViewData["ListOfStatus"]) %>
```

that will make a list with the element that you marked as selected ( `Selected = true`), as the default (selected) item.

Answer (score 3):

Try [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492883.aspx):

```
<%=Html.DropDownList("memberInvoiceStatus", ViewData["memberInvoiceStatus"] as SelectList, "--DEFAULT TEXT--")%>
```

Comment: That sets a default value, yes, but basically it's a "no option selected" value.  That can be handy and is usually the way to go.  I was assuming that he wanted it to take a default value from the model -- say in an edit view instead of a new view.

Comment: @tvanfosson, there's not enough information in the question. I am just guessing here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you want to have the value reflect the current value of the model.  If not, you can use the version of the helper that allows you to specify a default, "unselected" option for the list.  If so, you probably want to have two different attributes in your model or view data -- I almost always use a strongly-typed view model for this -- one for the property and one for the list of choices.  The helper will pick up the default for the select list from the property value, if available.

Ex:

```
<%= Html.DropDownList( "memberInvoiceStatus", ViewData["memberInvoiceOptions"] as SelectList ) %>
```

where `memberInvoiceStatus` is the property (returned on post and containing default on view) and `memberInvoiceOptions` is the select list.  Using a mode (the way I would go) it would look like:

```
 public class InvoiceViewModel
 {
      public int MemberInvoiceStatus { get; set; }
      public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> MemberInvoiceOptions { get; set; }
      ...
 }


 <%= Html.DropDownList( "MemberInvoiceStatus", Model.MemberInvoiceOptions ) %>
```

Using strongly-typed HtmlHelper extensions is probably even better, but requires using the MvcFutures assembly or waiting until MVC 2.0.